# How to deal with tot big spaces between words when justified in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Looking for a solution, but also for ideas.

Writing a book about 500 pages, some of the lines must be justified because there is a very long word and it breaks before the long word and then there is a huge space between words. And it is kind of ugly.

I mostly detect them by second read and some of them I correct rewriting, some of them braking the long word (hyphenating it), or reducing slightly the word separation if that helps.

But this is a manual process, ugly, and not consistent.

Any idea how can I identify those loose lines easily, and ideas to do with them?

Comment: The golden rule, really, is don't use Word for typesetting. It's meant for office letters, not real books. Look at something 'proper' like QuarkExpress, it will do half of this for you automatically, including some rather smart hyphenation & justification rules. It will also look a whole lot better, Word can't kern to save its life  :\

Comment: Hope the thread could help you, "[why are there wide spaces between some words in my document](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/why-are-there-wide-spaces-between-some-words-in-my/90857c21-ab90-40b1-b9b7-c06acce64e59)"

Comment: Presumably Word's automatic hyphenation does not do what you need? (Page Layout tab->Page Setup group->Hyphenation)

Comment: @Tetsujin, disagree. If for scientific books (math, phys), then LaTeX. QE is currently very different, very dynamic/web contents creation. Word is by the nature of it crazy, but I can say, it is possible to write large documents. I recommend external reference manager however. LaTeX can kill your productivity. Think about a secretary in all the mentioned cases if you reached Director level.

Answer (score 1):

If you're breaking words manually, you're doing it wrong. Word supports automatic hyphenation and also allows you to manually specify whether to hyphenate a word or not. Just go to *Layout* tab and select *Hyphenation*

[image]

For more information read [Control hyphenation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/control-hyphenation-7d4d2a38-b0e2-4f04-873a-0a8d48ac3923)

Answer (score 0):

Word's full justification algorithm stretches out the words, adding space between words. What you could do is save the document in 2003 mode, so .doc, then goto Home, Options and find the option at the bottom called 'Do justification like WordPerfect'. Then justification is done by squeezing words, rather then by add spacing them out.