# Stop Microsoft 365 Word from splitting words across lines

Tags: microsoft-word

I am writing some text in Microsoft Word. For example if I write:

> I really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really do not want “really” to be split across 2 lines!!!

Unfortunately, the words get split at the end of the line, so that "really" is split into "reall" and "y", as seen in this screenshot.

[image]

I have tried turning off hyphenation, without success. The split does not contain a hyphen, so it makes sense that hyphenation does not influence it.

[image]

How can I ask Microsoft Word to keep words intact?

Comment: Have you tried anything to fix it? Like things in File, Options

Comment: This answer might be relevant https://superuser.com/a/1579212/19943

Comment: Turn on display of non-printing formatting. What is showing between the words? If it is an open circle, that is a non-breaking space.  Can you attach a link to a document doing this?

Comment: @Cristian Riccio what font are you using? Does this also happen with a different font (standard font like Arial)?

Comment: @Loeli Changing the font makes no difference but you drew my attention to the "Styles" section in the "Home" tab and I fixed the problem. See my answer below. Thanks!

Comment: @CristianRiccio got it - in your answer, it would be interesting which style you used previously and what the setting was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the paragraph, go to the "Home" tab, in the "Styles" section, click "Normal". The words no longer split across 2 lines.

Answer (score -1):

Simply stop word from hyphenating your sentence.

Select your sentence, then right-click, choose `Paragraph`, `Line and Page Breaks`, `Don't Hyphenate`.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's hyphenating, it looks like word wrap is acting up.

Comment: @spikey_richie True, it should hyphenate at real-ly, but that can be a language issue. So it's still worth a try.

Comment: Stopping hyphenation did not help, unfortunately.